I have shuffled detections from a grid. How do I order them into a grid?
I created a Python code that recognizes and crops faces. But the problem is that it crops the faces randomly and not in the order in the original image that contains all the faces.
What is required please: is that the code crops the faces in order from the top to the right until it reaches the last face.
Please put the code with a folder named (Input Images) that contains the image that contains the collected faces.
And create a folder named Output Images that stores the cropped faces..
With the face recognition xml file haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml text
The Code:
import os
import cv2
import numpy as np
import os, os.path
# Load the cascade classifier
#download this here https://raw.githubusercontent.com/opencv/opencv/4.x/data/haarcascades/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml just go there and ctrl + s
face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier("haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml")


#rename a file 
#for dirname in os.listdir("."):
#    if os.path.isdir(dirname):
#        for i, filename in enumerate(os.listdir(dirname)):
#            os.rename(dirname + "/" + filename, dirname + "/" + str(i) + ".jpg")

# Read the input image
img = cv2.imread("Input Images/image.jpg")
#let's double the size of our image
img_double=cv2.resize(img,None,fx=1,fy=1,interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
# let's do the resizing by exact dimensions
image_resize=cv2.resize(img,(600,700),interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)


# Convert into grayscale
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Detect faces
faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale( gray, 
    scaleFactor=1.1, 
    minNeighbors=5, 
    minSize=(150, 150), )


# loop over all detected faces
if len(faces) > 0:
   for i, (x,y,w,h) in enumerate(faces):
       
      
      #face = img[y:y+h, x:x+w]
      face = img[y-65:y+h+40,x-40:x+w+55]
   
  
    # cv2.imshow(f"Cropped Face {i}", face)

      cv2.imwrite("Output Images/" f'0{i}.jpg', face)
      print(f"0{i}.jpg is saved")

  
# concatenate image Vertically 
#Verti = np.concatenate((img, img), axis=0) 

# Number of all detected faces      
print("[INFO] Found {0} Faces.".format(len(faces)))


# display the image with detected faces
cv2.imshow('scaling_exact',image_resize)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

Original image
illustrative example
What is required please: is that the code crops the faces in order from the top to the right until it reaches the last face.
example
[Original image]
(https://i.sstatic.net/mdTMAMpD.jpg)

All you have to do is collect the (x,y,w,h) values and sort by y and x as needed.  You're not required to pull them in the order it gives them to you.

Can you post original image? this doesn't have  rectangle such as 4200004, 4200016, , etc.

thank you toyota Supra
I have added the (original image). But I have removed the lines to put squares on the face from the code because I don't need them.

this reads like homework. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

You cannot just sort by y and x due to slight variations in y. You need to quantize the values into ranges about the size of the spaces from image to image vertically.

suggestion: try clustering with k=1..N clusters, assess worst stddev for each of those, and pick the smallest k that's below a threshold. that will tell you the number of rows, and the points in each row. now you can just sort each row individually. done. there is a bunch written in the literature on such approaches.

One way of quantizing is to round the coordinates to some value that is larger than the variation in the y values.

I would not recommend rounding. that relies on you having some idea where the center lines are supposed to be. simply dividing the entire image's height into equal parts assumes a lot that can't be assumed.

This is a sorting task.
Assuming you've found all the face boxes, now calculate the center of each box. We'll work with those center points.
You would assume that the points form a grid.
You don't know the number of rows, so you'll have to calculate that.
To do that, we'll cluster the Y coordinates into k=1..N clusters, for the smallest k such that all the clusters have "low" variance. If a cluster has to hold more than one row, its variance would be noticeably larger than that of a cluster that holds a single row.
For that threshold, I'll use 200 here, because rows are further apart than that, and the variation in Y in each row is well below that.
import numpy as np
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

# some points I picked out of your picture
boxes = np.array([
    [  90,  166,  180,  312],
    [ 485,  205,  148,  258],
    [ 853,  183,  182,  288],
    [1229,  220,  186,  294],
    [1647,  222,  158,  256],
    [2024,  178,  132,  250],
    [  71,  894,  162,  280],
    [ 460,  867,  166,  302],
    [ 849,  921,  174,  336],
    [1254,  918,  180,  318],
    [1612,  932,  204,  304],
    [2009,  905,  188,  302],
    [  86, 1643,  152,  298],
    [ 435, 1600,  210,  284],
    [ 825, 1569,  208,  336],
    [1256, 1616,  170,  304],
    [1605, 1586,  182,  284],
    [2008, 1606,  190,  292],
    [  71, 2310,  160,  284],
    [ 448, 2313,  214,  274],
    [ 836, 2387,  168,  278],
    [1237, 2362,  172,  298],
    [1624, 2346,  180,  260],
    [2020, 2327,  174,  232]])

points = boxes[:, 0:2] + boxes[:, 2:4] / 2
np.random.shuffle(points)

def find_least_k(values, threshold):
    for k in range(1, len(values) + 1):
        model = KMeans(n_clusters=k) # for testing, add random_state=0
        fit = model.fit(values.reshape(-1, 1))
        centers = fit.cluster_centers_.flatten()
        labels = fit.labels_
        stddevs = np.array([values[labels == i].std() for i in range(k)])

        if stddevs.max() < threshold:
            return k, centers, labels

Y_values = points[:, 1]
best_k, centers, labels = find_least_k(Y_values, threshold=200)

# sorting the rows
permutation = np.argsort(centers)
invperm = np.argsort(permutation)

centers = centers[permutation]
labels = invperm[labels]

points_by_row = [
    points[labels == i]
    for i in range(best_k)
]

points_sorted = np.array([
    row[np.argsort(row[:, 0])]
    for row in points_by_row
])

print(points_sorted)

input, output:


[[[ 180.  322.]
  [ 559.  334.]
  [ 944.  327.]
  [1322.  367.]
  [1726.  350.]
  [2090.  303.]]

 [[ 152. 1034.]
  [ 543. 1018.]
  [ 936. 1089.]
  [1344. 1077.]
  [1714. 1084.]
  [2103. 1056.]]

 [[ 162. 1792.]
  [ 540. 1742.]
  [ 929. 1737.]
  [1341. 1768.]
  [1696. 1728.]
  [2103. 1752.]]

 [[ 151. 2452.]
  [ 555. 2450.]
  [ 920. 2526.]
  [1323. 2511.]
  [1714. 2476.]
  [2107. 2443.]]]

